# Solving numerical equation with PolyLog function

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve numerically some equations involving the PolyLog function, for example:

`NSolve[-PolyLog[2, -z] == 10^5, z, Reals]`

However, I encounter the error:

> NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods
> available to NSolve.

I tried using a series approximation to PolyLog, and it works, but the answer is not well-behaved in the number of terms (i.e., it changes dramatically if I change the approximation order).

How do I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: The `NSolve` work fine in v13.3.1

Comment: As well in 13.3.0 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

The LHS slowly tends to infinity as

```
Asymptotic[-PolyLog[2, -z], z -> Infinity]
```

> `Log[z]^2/2`

shows. Now we estimate the location of the root by

```
Solve[Log[z]^2/2 == 10^5&&z>=1, z, Reals]
```

> `{{z -> E^(200 Sqrt[5])}}`

Finally, indicating the range,

```
NSolve[-PolyLog[2, -z] == 10^5 && z >= E^(200 Sqrt[5])/2 && 
z <= 2*E^(200 Sqrt[5]), z, Reals]
```

> `{{z -> 1.66264*10^194}}`

does the work. The result is not from real world.

Comment: It should be noticed `FunctionDomain[-PolyLog[2, -z], z]` results in `z >= -1`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Solve` instead of `NSolve`.

```
Solve[-PolyLog[2, -z] == 10^5, z, Reals]
```

[image]

Comment: A spot on the Sun: `Solve[Log[Log[Log[z]]] == 10^5, z, Reals]` results in `{}`.

Comment: [CASE:5069610] has been submitted by me.